# url request from python code

Tags: python, arrays, json

```
import json
import urllib2    
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.energyhive.com/mobile_proxy/getCurrentValuesSummary?token=VtxgIC2UnhfUmXe_pBksov7-lguAQMZD')    
content = response.read()
print(content)
```

from the code i get

```
[{"cid":"PWER","data":[{"1437957635000":37}],"sid":"9271","units":"kWm","age":6},{"cid":"PWER_GAC","data":[{"1437957635000":0}],"sid":"9271","units":null,"age":6},{"cid":"FBAK_IMM","data":[{"1437957629000":0}],"sid":"9271","units":null,"age":12},{"cid":"PWER_IMM","data":[{"1437957629000":0}],"sid":"9271","units":null,"age":12}]
```

What i can't work out is getting the data from PWER_GAC

Comment: Can you please explain what data you want to get with example?

Comment: i would like to take the value (data) from PWER_GAC and save the data to a text file.

Comment: Do you mean `data` key from the dictionary with `cid` as `PWER_GAC` ?

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output? So far I understood that if the `cid` parameter is 'PWER_GAC', you want to save the `data` parameter  to a file, but how would you like to save it?

Comment: In the end result i would like to be able to store the results in text or sql  and when the data reaches a value, sends me a (get or, email, notify prowl)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to load it as a JSON and go to the correct key:

```
for x in json.loads(content):
    if x["cid"] == "PWER_GAC":
        print(x["units"])
        print(x["age"])
        print(x["sid"])
        print(x["data"])
        print(x["cid"])
```

Comment: in the data, my requirement is after the colon example 267 
[{u'1438022036000': 267}]  
coding so far is

import json
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.energyhive.com/mobile_proxy/getCurrentValuesSummary?token=VtxgIC2UnhfUmXe_pBksov7-lguAQMZD')
content = response.read()
for x in json.loads(content):
    if x["cid"] == "PWER_GAC":
        print(x["data"])

Answer (score 1):

The data you are receiving is a string, and you can convert it into Python data structures with `json.loads()`. Then iterate through the dicts until the cid matches what you are looking for.

```
content = json.loads(content)
for i in content:
    if(i['cid'] == 'PWER_GAC'):
        print(i)
```